# Sending numerous packets instead of 1 SSL Python

Tags: python, scapy, modbus

I have set up an experiment where I pass Modbus traffic over a SSL tunnel (this being the first thing I've ever done in python). I am able to send and receive data but when I send one request numerous requests are actually sent (see screenshot)

[image]

I've tried numerous configurations including (in both client and server):

```
send()--no change
sendall() --no change
setblocking(1)
setblocking(0)--doesn't read all the data
```

On the server side:
`if data == Read_Coils_Answer`-- I don't think I'm converting the big endian properly for comparison and this didn't work
`while data:` --the while loop seems to be the only way to prevent either side from stopping short with a "Broken Pipe" error. So this is what I'm using.

I eventually plan to use a `for` loop (now commented out and set to 4).

My Server code:

```
from ModLib import *
import socket, ssl, sys, pprint

try:
bindsocket = socket.socket()
bindsocket.bind(('', 502))
bindsocket.listen(5)
bindsocket.setblocking(1)

def do_something(connstream, data):
    readCoilsReq = str('\x01\x01\x00')
    answer = str(ModbusPDU01_Read_Coils_Answer)
    while data:
        print ("Request Recevied from Client:")
        print pprint.pformat(data)
        connstream.send(answer)
        print ("Answer Sent to Client")
        print pprint.pformat(answer)
    return False

def deal_with_client(connstream):
    data = connstream.recv(64)
    while data:
        if not do_something(connstream, data):
            break
        data = connstream.recv(64)

while True:
    newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
    connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(newsocket,
                         server_side=True,
                         certfile="server.crt",
                         keyfile="server.key",
                         ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    try:
        deal_with_client(connstream)
    finally:
        connstream.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        connstream.close()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
print ("\nTerminating Session at User Request")
print ("No More Data Will be Sent/Recieved\n")
sys.exit(1)
```

My Client Side code:

```
from ModLib import *
from time import sleep
import socket, ssl, pprint

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s,
           ca_certs="server.crt",
           cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)

ssl_sock.connect(('localhost', 502))
ssl_sock.setblocking(1)

readCoils = ModbusPDU01_Read_Coils()

#for i in range(4):
sleep(2)
ssl_sock.sendall(str(readCoils))
print ("Request for Read Coils Sent")

#start receive
data = ssl_sock.recv(64)
print ("Response from Server:")
print pprint.pformat(data)

if False: #from the python docs
    ssl_sock.write("""GET / HTTP/1.0\r
    Host: www.verisign.com\n\n""")

    data = ssl_sock.read()

    ssl_sock.close()
```

Comment: You're reading data in 64 byte chunks on the server side, and calling `do_something()` for every chunk. So you don't (necessarily) get multiple requests, but multiple chunks.

Comment: I've tried changing that value too. To either recv(), recv(64), recv(32) and recv(1024); the result is identical in all configurations? My understanding from Wireshark is that the packets are only 32 bytes each, so 64 should be more than enough to process the entire packet...you may be right, I just double check and the application data is actually 1120.

Comment: Well, your `while data` loop in `do_something()` is probably causing that issue. `data` will never change in that loop - so you're looping indefinitely over the same chunk of data, creating the impression that multiple requests were received. Also, you're already reading from the socket in loop in the outer function (`deal_with_client()`).

Comment: hmmm...I was thinking it was that while loop also; let me try to 'reset' the value of data at the end of each iteration through the loop.

Comment: No, just remove the loop entirely, you don't need it.

Comment: But when I remove the loop entirely, I get a "broken pipe" error. The while loop was my 'fix' for that. --That works until I add the for loop and try to send the 4 requests. Then I get the broken pipe error after the third request although the server is still listening.

Comment: Well, you're `break`ing the loop and returning from `deal_with_client()` after sending one response, which in turn will close the socket => broken pipe. You'd need to write server in a way that it keeps reading data indefinitely and can deal with several subsequent requests. But I don't know the ModBus protocol, so unfortunately I can't tell you how to do that in detail.

Comment: Think I got it; I just did away with `do_something()` all together and am doing all the processing in `deal_with_client`; seems to be producing the output as desired. Thank you for your time @LukasGraf

Comment: One last bit of advice: You should move the *definition of functions* out of the `try` block of your `try..except`. Try and keep the `try` part as short as possible, ideally only wrapping code that can actually raise the exception you want to catch. Which in the case of `KeyboardInterrupt` is pretty much everything, but not function definitions. I'd suggest to create a `main()` function that encapsulates the meat of your code ([like this](https://gist.github.com/lukasgraf/341732ee801e90f0af0a)), and then do `try: main(); except KeyboardInterrupt` - much easier to read.

Comment: Ok, I'll work on that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `do_something()` loop was not necessary, as the `deal_with_client()` loop was doing the same thing. I removed `do_something()` and put the code in `deal_with_client()` which allows me to keep the connection open (see below)

```
from ModLib import *
import socket, ssl, sys, pprint

try:
    bindsocket = socket.socket()
    bindsocket.bind(('', 502))
    bindsocket.listen(5)
    bindsocket.setblocking(1)

    def deal_with_client(connstream):
        data = connstream.recv(1120)
        answer = str(ModbusPDU01_Read_Coils_Answer())
        while data:
            print ("Request Received from Client:")
            print pprint.pformat(data)
            connstream.send(answer)
            print ("Answer Sent to Client")
            print pprint.pformat(answer)
            data = connstream.recv(1120)

    while True:
        newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
        connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(newsocket,
                                     server_side=True,
                                     certfile="server.crt",
                                     keyfile="server.key",
                                    ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
        try:
            deal_with_client(connstream)
        finally:
            connstream.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            connstream.close()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("\nTerminating Session at User Request")
    print ("No More Data Will be Sent/Received\n")
    sys.exit(1)
```